# Save 'compare project' view

Tags: compare, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm trying to save compare view for few projects, to avoid clicking through to get it for all of them over and over again. Can this be done? Freshly pulled SonarQube, 5.6.1.

[Documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE50/Compare+Projects) and my own research so far proved fruitless to point to any way of doing that, so I keep recreating same project comparison. Any pointers are welcome.

EDIT:

Attaching two screenshots.

[image: Compare Projects in navbar]

[image: Empty again]

Comment: Can you [edit] to expand on what you mean by "compare view"?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam - added screenshot where in the navbar is Compare Projects view and how it looks each time I go there, no matter what have I been comparing previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you cannot save configurations on the *Compare* page. It's a known limitation that won't be fixed, see [SONAR-4479](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-4479). As per ticket, note that this *Compare* functionally is planned to be removed in 6.x series.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply, link and deprecation warning!